# How do I determine the maximum or the minimum of in the range the function in the range $B=\left \{ \left ( x,y \right ):x^2+y^2\leq 1 \right \}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, multivariable-calculus

How do I determine the maximum or the minimum of in the range the function $f(x,y)=x^3+y^3 $in the range $B=\left \{ \left ( x,y \right ):x^2+y^2\leq 1 \right \}$?

As a continuous function f must have (the entire area) in B a maximum and a minimum. How do  I show that they can lie on the outskirts of B. How do I examine the behavior of f at the edge of B?

I know that $f_x=3x^2,f_y=y=3y^2,f_{xx}=6x, f_{yy}=6y, f_{xy}=0$.

I have calculated that minimum and maximum are in point $(0,0)$.Saddle point is $(0,0)$.

Problem is I but do not know how to show max and min in the interval, and examine the behavior in function?

Comment: Note you have a typo in $f_y$ -- should be just $3y^2$ (omit the $=y=$ part). Also the set over which you want max/min is not an interval, it's often called a disc.

Comment: Since you have shown that the global max or min doesn't really exist, there are several ways to find the maximum/minimum of the function on the boundary. One way is lagrange multipliers, the other would be to reparameterize the function into one of a single variable along the edge (one such is the typical parameterization of a circular path) and use methods from calc 1

Comment: @Triatticus SInce the region is compact, it's not really correct to say "since you have shown global max or min doesn't really exist". Better would be to say OP has shown no max/min in the interior, which in fact he has not, the Jacobian being zero at the only interior critical point.

Comment: Such a test is typically enough for a low level undergrad course in calculus, of course. But the question was more about the boundary anyways..granted The level of the original post is hard to guess

Answer (score 3):

If $(0,0)$ is really a saddle, it can't be the max or min. Actually this is clear if one lets $x=0$ since then $f=y^3$ which takes on both positive and negative values near $0.$ Anyway your first derivatives already show there is no critical point other than $(0,0)$ in the interior. So the rest of the problem would be to parametrize the boundary, say as $x=\cos t, \ y= \sin t,$ and then get max/min of the result of plugging these into $x^3+y^3.$

Added note: The jacobian is $36xy$ which at the critical point $(0,0)$ is zero, meaning we do not get the type of the local behavior of $f$ near the origin from the jacobian alone. [In particular the origin is not a saddle point in the usual quadratic sense.] This is why one must do something else, such as looking along an axis, to determine whether there might be a local max or min at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

By symmetry, $\min_B f=-\max_B f$, and since $x^3+y^3\leq|x|^3+|y|^3$ the max is  taken in the closed first quadrant. From $f(\lambda x,\lambda y)=\lambda^3 f(x,y)$ it then follows that the max is taken on the boundary of $B$. Therefore we have to consider the pullback
$$\hat f(t):=f(\cos t,\sin t)=\cos^3 t+\sin^3 t\qquad\left(0\leq t\leq{\pi\over2}\right) \ .$$
One computes
$$\hat f'(t)=3\cos t\sin t(\sin t-\cos t)$$
with a single zero $t_*:={\pi\over 4}$ in the interior of the given $t$-interval $I$. Our "candidate list" then consists of $t_*$ and the endpoints of $I$:
$$\max_{(x,y)\in B} f(x,y)=\max\left\{\hat f(t_*),\ \hat f(0),\ \hat f\bigl({\pi\over2}\bigr)\right\}=1\ .$$

Comment: How do you get the last step: f(0) and f(pi/2) ?